# Loop of test suites in a CasperJS test file results in random failures in the shell

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I would like check the title of several website. So, when I want do that with the "test object", I randomly get different results. I mean, when I run the shell command "casperjs test ..." :

- Sometimes, my shell displays all the test (its Ok!)
- Sometimes (screenshot #1), all tests is not done
- Sometimes (screenshot #2), I get a fail "check title" test, the previous open(url) didn't load the new url (?!)

The screenshot of my shell: [image: http://s16.postimg.org/auwhiqkpg/Sans_titre.jpg]

My code:

```
casper.options.loadImages = false;

var lines = [
  "http://www.jeuxvideo.com;JEUXVIDEO.COM - La Référence des Jeux Vidéo sur PC et Consoles !",
  "http://www.google.fr;Google",
  "http://casperjs.org/;CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS",
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
  "http://stackoverflow.com/;Stack Overflow",
  "http://9gag.com/;9GAG - Why So Serious?",
  "http://eu.blizzard.com/fr-fr/;Blizzard Entertainment",
  "http://openclassrooms.com/;OpenClassrooms, Le Site du Zéro - Les cours les plus ouverts du Web",
  "http://lesjoiesducode.fr/;Les joies du code ",
  "http://www.developpez.com/;Developpez.com, le club des développeurs et IT Pro",
];

function main(){
  this.each(lines, function(self, line){
    var tab = line.split(";");
    casper.test.begin("test : "+tab[0], 1, function suite(test){
      casper.start().then(function(){

        this.then(function(){
          this.open(tab[0]);
        });

        this.then(function (){
          this.echo(this.currentHTTPStatus);
          test.assertTitle(tab[1]);
        });

      }).run(function(){
        test.done();
      });
    });
  });
}

casper.start().then(main).run();
```

My versions :

```
casperjs version : 1.1.0-beta3
phantomjs version : 1.9.7
```

Why sometimes, all tests aren't done and why sometimes le new url isn't loaded ? (whereas the open(url) is in a .then)

Comment: What do you mean with "sometimes"? How often does this happen? What are the specific errors? There is no screenshot, so what screenshot are you talking about?

Comment: This problem often occurs and there aren't errors :/ My bad about the screenchot, I meant the screenshot of my shell (you see the commands "1" and "2" in red)

Comment: When I execute the .js, I get sometimes the result of the command "1", and sometimes the result if the command "2". The screenshot of my shell shows the randoms issues I have. In the screenshot of my shell, commands are the same and I didn't change anything in the script, but I got randoms issues.

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: `page.onRessourceTimeout` is not an event for `casper.on`. It is set on the PhantomJS page instance behind the scenes: `casper.page.onRessourceTimeout = function(){ ... };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `start` and `run` only **once** in your test case and never outside of `casper.test.begin`. You don't need the `main` function as a step for `then`. Also, you can further condense your script.

```
  lines.forEach(function(line){
    var tab = line.split(";");
    casper.test.begin("test : "+tab[0], 1, function suite(test){
      casper.start(tab[0]).then(function (){
        this.echo(this.currentHTTPStatus);
        test.assertTitle(tab[1]);
      }).run(function(){
        test.done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help =) I update my first post, the new script doesn't test all the links of the array...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the above script and PhantomJS 1.9.8 on Windows.

Comment: Do you think the OS (or virtual box? I use Mint) is the issue ? For the version of PhantomJS, I read in the casperjs forum the phantomJS 1.9.8 isn't supported because little bugged (https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1068)

Comment: The OS shouldn't change anything and the only difference between 1.9.7 and 1.9.8 is the default value for SSL protocol. You should run casperjs with `--ssl-protocol=any`.

Comment: I add the argument but the issue stays the same.. I tested on another computer (virtualbox, xubuntu, phantomjs 1.9.7, nodejs v0.10.25, casperjs 1.1.0-beta3, I got the same issues here too. I will test on linux (Mint) computer without virtualbox

Comment: With the another linux computer, there is always the issue x) (one link test and stop). I'm going crazy haha x)

Comment: This is the complete script that I use: https://gist.github.com/artjomb/607f45f43888af8914b8

Comment: Roo man, Im soo stupid. I didn't notice your "line.forEach" is out of casper.start...And you saided that ! I just read "condense your script", I go wear a dunce cap, seriously -_-